# Use ModelAdmin form in any view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I've spent quite a bit of time setting up the `ModelAdmin` for my models, and I want to be able to basically reuse it elsewhere on my site, i.e., not just in the admin pages.

Specifically, I want to further subclass the `ModelAdmin` subclass I created and override some of the methods and attributes to be non-admin specific, then use that second subclass to create a form from a model in one of my ordinary (non-admin) views. **But I'm not sure how to get the form out of the `ModelAdmin` subclass or how to bind it to a specific model.**

So for instance, my `admin.py` looks something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['my_custom_field']
    readonly_fields = ['my_custom_field']

    def my_custom_field(self, instance):
        return "This is my admin page."
```

And this works real nice. Now in I want to subclass this as:

```
class MyNonAdmin(MyAdmin):
    def my_custom_field(self, instance):
        return "This is NOT my admin page!"
```

Now I want to use the `MyNonAdmin` in a view function to generate a form bound to a particular model, and use that form in a template. I'm just not sure how to do that.

**Update**

I found how to render the form, but it doesn't include any of the `readonly_fields`. Rendering the form looks like this:

```
def view_func(request, id):j
    res = get_object_or_404(ModelClass, pk=int(id))
    admin = MyNonAdmin(ModelClass, None)
    form = admin.get_form(request, res)

    return render(request, 'my_template.html', dict(
        form=form,
    ))
```

But as I said, it only renders the form itself, not the other `readonly_fields` which is what I really care about.

Comment: did you heard of django-grappelli ?

Comment: No, but it looks like it's just some style and features for the admin site. I don't want the admin site, I just want the same form/display in a different view.